# LabelEncoding the target variable improves model massively vs. one-hot-encoding the same

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm using a Random Forest classifier on text data transformed into tf-idf (both the features and the target variable are text, the target variable being company names). Since using a LabelEncoder adds ordinality where there is none, I first tried to one-hot encode the companies (the full company name would be one column). This resulted in a 0.48 score. I changed it so that the companies are now LabelEncoded, and the score (with cross-validation but with the same parameters) jumped to 0.75.

I have two questions related to this.

Sklearn's [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder) does mention that the LabelEncoder can be used to encode target variables. Does that mean the added ordinality is somehow negated, and it's actually okay to use it to encode the target variable this way?

Also, can you help me understand what lead to this big improvement? Is it a "fake" improvement somehow caused by the added ordinality?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Scikit-Learn classifiers can handle string targets as-is. Actually, this should be the default/intended setup.

When you encode a string target into numeric target (whether using `LabelEncoder`, `OneHotEncoder`, or anything else), you begin to mis-represent the problem. There is a chance that Scikit-Learn inspects your data, and decides to use some other ML algorithm behind the scenes (eg. your original classification problem looks like a regression problem, and will be approached that way).

Applying `LabelEncoder` to a string target shouldn't change anything. You are using a classifier and, by definition, most Scikit-Learn classifiers treat the target as an unordered classification problem. That is, transforming a label from strings to integers won't make Scikit-Learn treat it as ordinal, because Scikit-Learn codebase does not contain any ordinal modelling logic at all!

Applying `OneHotEncoder` will turn a single target column into multiple (binary-) target columns. If you see a massive change in model performance, then it could be that Scikit-Learn is approaching your problem as a multi-output classification problem now.

TLDR: Don't encode/transformation your string target in any way! There is no need for it, and by doing so, you risk mis-representing your problem.